# $stateProvider leads to blank page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've been dealing with a weird issue in angular where I get a blank page. *I've found some similar questions in here but the answers just didn't work.*

Well the thing is that I have the following config

```
$stateProvider.state('store.home', {
  url: '/?cart',
  templateUrl: 'store/home/home.html',
  controller: 'store.home as vm',
  data: {
    title: 'Home'
  }
});
```

Now that `cart` param is only a way we have to pop up the cart in the UI if it's present, BUT if I send that parameter `cart=open`, `cart=close` or any other parameter like `foo=bar` I keep getting a blank page, if I go to `/` the page works as expected, any thoughts?

Everything works as expected if I'm using `$state.go('home', { cart: 'open'}` - it just doesn't work if accessed directly.

Comment: Show us _how_ you _"send that parameter"_.

Comment: like this works -> `$state.go('store.home', { cart: 'open' });`

going directly like, copying pasting the url and pressing enter is what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario should be working. I did not make so much changes, just created [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/f2R2kpeD4ZXlGuwF87Uk?p=preview).

Try it [here](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/f2R2kpeD4ZXlGuwF87Uk/#/?cart=open), were you you can change [URL params ?cart=xxxx](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/f2R2kpeD4ZXlGuwF87Uk/#/?cart=open)

The controller just has a function go, taking one param and redirecting to `'store.home'`:

```
var controllerSH = ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state){
  var go = function(param){
    $state.go('store.home', { cart: param })
  };
  return {
    go : go,
  }
}];
```

And then with your original *state* def and `angularjs` 1.3.4, `UI-Router` 0.2.13, all these links are working:

```
// controller function go
<button ng-click="vm.go('open')">
<button ng-click="vm.go('close')">
// href:
<a href="#/?cart=open">
<a href="#/?cart=close">
// ui-sref:
<a ui-sref="store.hom({cart:'open'})">
<a ui-sref="store.hom({cart:'close'})">
```

*NOTE: in fact, there is part which is not in the question snippet - parent of our state:*

```
.state('store', {
  abstract: true,
  template: '<ui-view />',
})
```

Try the [life demo](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/f2R2kpeD4ZXlGuwF87Uk/#/?cart=open), observe the [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/f2R2kpeD4ZXlGuwF87Uk?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If you're pasting a URL into the location bar and hitting enter, keep in mind, that if you don't put `#` in front of your "state URL" (including `ui-router`'s "search params", which are not really [searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.searchParams)), you're modifying the URL and forcing a page reload. See [this guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) about configuring your web-server to support with html5mode or just put the `#` in your URLs and turn html5mode in `ui-router` off (`$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);`).